# Direct sum of vector bundles is a trivial bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I am reading an article and it states that if $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, $X$ is a Compact space and $\xi$ a (finite dimensional and locally trivial) $F$-vector bundle, then there exists another $F$-vector bundle $\xi'$ (fin. dim and loc. trivial) such that $\xi \oplus \xi’$ is isomorphic to a trivial vector bundle.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: On a side note, something similar happens in algebraic geometry: if $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ is an affine scheme, then vector bundles (or locally free sheaves) over $X$ correspond to projective modules over $A$, and projective modules are exactly the direct summands of free modules (where free modules correspond to globally trivial vector bundles).

Comment: You can find a proof here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum+of+vector+bundles#whitney_summands_of_trivial_vector_bundles